# Navigate to a page after a GET request in express?

Tags: ajax, express, server-side-rendering

I'm fairly new to express and was wondering how to navigate to a page as a result of a GET request? I'm building my page from a template, and the following works if I manually input the '/id' url:

```
const express = require('express');
const template = require('./template.js');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(template({
    body: "Home",
    title: "Home Title"
  }))
});

app.get('/id', (req, res) => {
  console.log("received get request for id");
  res.send(template({
    body: "id",
    title: "ID"
  }));
});

const server = app.listen(port);
console.log("listening...");
```

But if I send a GET request from the client, it gets received and nothing happens. Any tips or help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. How do you call the get method from your front-end? Ajax? or do you have a list of ids and you want to get a number as a parameter and then get a result with this id?

Comment: I call it with Ajax, and would like to navigate to the new URL and load the page that's generated by my template.